# How can I add an object to a collection without knowing it's type?

Tags: c#, xna

I added a "console" in my game, in which I can type commands, and receive a response (it's based on [this](http://xnaconsole.codeplex.com/)). I need to be able to access objects that I instantiate in my Game.cs in my console class. I can't pass them to the constructor, since I don't know how much there will be once the "engine" is done.

I tried using a method to add the objects to a `Dictionnary<string, object>` but I can't access the properties.

What I'd like to be able to do:

**Game1.cs**

```cs
TileMap tileMap = new TileMap();
BakuConsole console;

...

console = new BakuConsole(this, Content.Load<SpriteFont>("ConsoleFont"));
console.AddRef("tileMap", tileMap);
```

**BakuConsole.cs**

```cs
public void AddRef(/* some args */) {
   // halp!
}

public void Execute(string input) {
    switch (input)
    {
        case "some --command":
            console.WriteLine(g.ToString());
            // execute stuff, with an object that was added via AddRef()
            console.WriteLine("");
            console.Prompt(prompt, Execute);
            break;
        default:
            console.WriteLine("> " + input + " is not a valid command.");
            console.WriteLine("");
            console.Prompt(prompt, Execute);
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope I am clear enough. Thanks!

**Edit:**
I just don't want my constructor to grow too big in case I add more types:

```
TileMap tileMap = new TileMap();
OtherType1 ot1 = new OtherType1();
OtherType2 ot2 = new OtherType2();
OtherType3 ot3 = new OtherType3();
OtherType4 ot4 = new OtherType4();
OtherType5 ot5 = new OtherType5();
```

[IronPython](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main) does exactly what I want to do, and does it via Globals.Add("string", object"). However, I can't seem to find it in the source (of IronPython).

Comment: What do you mean that you don't know how much there will be? Could you give an example?

Comment: If you expect to have lots of objects like that, it could make sense to make one other type that contains those objects.

Comment: I was actually thinking about that. I could create a `GameObject` type, and extend everything from that......right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you described, you don't actually need a dictionary, you need several properties on some object, probably directly on `BakuConsole`;

```
class BakuConsole
{
    … // your current code here

    public TileMap TileMap { get; set; }
    public OtherType1 OtherType1 { get; set; }
    …
}
```

Then, you can set it like this:

```
console.TileMap = tileMap;
console.OtherType1 = otherType1;
…
```

And then when you use it, you won't have any problems with accessing properties.

Comment: That works. I guess adding a property is less of a hassle than adding to the constructor. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are passing a reference of Game to the Console class. Why don't you use that reference to access what you need from the Game class?

Comment: Trying to access `tileMap` from `game` gives me `'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game' does not contain a definition for 'tileMap'`

Comment: How about creating a property for each object you want to retrieve?

Comment: Can you post the signature of your Console constructor?

Comment: `public BakuConsole(Game game, SpriteFont font) : base((Game)game)`

Answer (score 0):

You neeed to specify the class name in dictionary of which object you are going to add in dictionary.
Suppose, I had to add "`Game1`" objects,then we should initialize dictionary in following way...

```
Dictionary<string, Game1> dicDemo = new Dictionary<string, Game1>();
Game1 objgame1 = new Game1();
dicDemo.Add(string.Empty,objgame1);
```

Comment: Even then, it will not compile, the compiler will throw out `'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game' does not contain a definition for 'tileMap'`